# Honeywell VR8300A3500 Single Stage Heat Gas Valve to Ecobee3 with C wire

Tags: hvac, furnace, boiler, thermostat-c-wire, heat

Hey everyone have a quick question regarding a honeywell VR8300A3500 Single Stage Heat Gas Valve and the introduction of a Ecobee3 wifi enabled thermostat with a "C" wire. just want to make sure i am understanding this correctly and have drawn out the right circuit. The TH/TR stand for TH- Thermostat and TR is the common correct? below is my drawn out circuit along with a picture of the valve and diagram of the valve. Thanks. Also i have a 24v hightemp switch in series as shown.
[image]

[image]

Comment: just want to make sure this will work the way it is currently drawn. Thanks

Comment: What is the `+` in the diagram?  Typically, `TR` represents the terminal that the transformer connects to, while `TH` is the terminal the thermostat connects to.

Answer (score 1):

The only goof is that the 24V from the transformer is AC so it really doesn't have a + or - side to it -- it's more or less a "hot/neutral" thing instead.  Otherwise, what you have drawn out will work just fine.